# Designing an app for iPad / iPhone retina display

Tags: gui-design, guidelines, ios, design, screen-resolution

I am working for a client to develop an iOS app both for iPhone and iPad including for retina displays.

The client is going to get the UX designs himself. We use the [Apple's iOS Human Interface Design Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) to whoever is designing the UX for our apps.

In the article it explicitly mentions that:

```
____________________________________________________________________________
|                 | Size for iPad          | Size for high-resolution iPad |
|_________________|________________________|_______________________________|
| Launch image    |                        |                               |
| (required for   | 768 x 1004 (portrait)  | 1536 x 2008 (portrait)        |                  
| all apps)       | 1024 x 748 (landscape) | 2048 x 1496 (landscape)       |
|_________________|________________________|_______________________________|
```

Does this mean that for each screen design (besides the launch screen) the designer has these canvas sizes as well?

Because, the screen size in [iPad specs](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) is 2048 x 1536 (portrait) and 1536 x 2048 (landscape). And for iPhone 4 the complete screen size 640 x 960 was used as canvas size!

UPDATE: Found reference to it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) under section "Launch Images"

Comment: I mean the UI designs usually provided as PSD files to us! I am asking what canvas size should he choose for iPad retina design

Comment: Ahh okay. Since the retina display is exactly 2x, starting with retina and downscaling seems the logical option. Downscale to half of retina and see how well it works; might be some tweaks if the non-retina display is harder to read; the text/ect will be less crisp

Comment: Yes, but I don't really egt the canvas size for retina. There is one in the iPad specs and one in the Design interface guidelines!

Comment: Here is a PDF with some useful information about what you have to think about regarding images etc.: http://f.cl.ly/items/012n0O023v2S2N1m3Q1t/How%20to%20Retinafy%20your%20Website.pdf (It is more a technical document than a UX document.)

Comment: I think the launch-image sizes are the full-display minus the status bar, which may or may not be hidden in your full app. Oh, I see Kit Grose's on the case :)

Comment: I finally found the exact answer in this link: http://bit.ly/LLEHK1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The discrepancy is due to the status bar (where the clock and wireless status is shown) which is 20px high on the regular display (and 40px on the retina display).

Whether that is also the size you should design the app UI to depends on whether your app runs full-screen (i.e. hides the status bar) or not.

Generally it should *not* hide the status bar unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: +1. I found a reference to it too. 
http://bit.ly/LLEHK1

Comment: @Ozair-Kafray: The URL is outdated, unfortunately...

Comment: @PerQuestedAronsson Here is the new link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/